# How update this div using Ajax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my razor view. The main point is when I the dropdown value change, update the `question-editor` div. As you can see, I'm invoking an `EditorFor`.

```
@model Contoso.MvcApplication.Models.Question.CreateQuestionViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create Open Question";
}

<h3>Create Question</h3>

<select id="question-type-dropdown" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
    <option value="MC">Multiple Choice</option>
    <option value="O">Open Question</option>
</select>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.QuestionSetId)
        <legend>Question Template</legend>

        <div id="question-editor">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Template, "_QuestionEditorBoxPartial")
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Here is the partial view, just contain an EditorModelFor to choose which viewtemplate should it use.

_QuestionEditorBox  (PartialView)

```
@model Contoso.Core.Base.QuestionTemplate
@Html.EditorForModel(Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionTemplateView(Model))
public abstract class Question
{
   public int Id {get;set;}
   public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}

public OpenQuestion : Question { ... }
public MultipleChoiceQuestion : Question { ... }

public class CreateQuestionViewModel
{
    public int QuestionSetId { get; set; }
    public QuestionTemplate Template { get; set; }
}
```

But when I did this, it does not display anything because I'm doing EditorFor two times with the same model. I tried to change the first EditorFor with a `PartialView`, but this is not gonna work because I need that the model binder catches my model.

**EDIT (AJAX METHOD):**

```
$("#question-type-dropdown").change(function () {
    $.get("/Question/UpdateQuestionEditorBox", { questionType: $(this).val() },
        function (data) {
            $("#question-editor").html(data);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to use a partial (not an editor template):

```
<div id="question-editor">
    @Html.Partial("_QuestionEditorBox.cshtml", Model.Template)
</div>
```

And then inside your partial:

```
@model Contoso.Core.Base.QuestionTemplate
@{
    ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix = "Template";
}
@Html.EditorForModel(Contoso.Core.QuestionRepositoryManager.GetQuestionTemplateView(Model))
```

Notice how I did set the `HtmlFieldPrefix` in order to preserve the navigational context into the partial and so generate proper names for the input fields in the corresponding editor template.

Also you mentioned updating the `question-editor` div with an AJAX call when the dropdown selection changes but you haven't shown any AJAX code to do that. I guess you have subscribed to the .change event of the dropdown somewhere and triggered an AJAX call.

Comment: Exactly, I haven't show the ajax method (I supposed that should irrelevant for the purpose).. I didn't have idea about TemplateInfo, it sounds great!! With this is like using EditorFor right?

Comment: Yes, setting the `HtmlFieldPrefix` allows you to control the navigational context in a template and thus the partial could act as an editor template.

Comment: Just for curiosity, you mention that this is a posibility, are there another ones?

Comment: Yes, there could be other possibilities as well, but that would depend on your project design and specific requirements. From the information you provided in your question that was the first solution that came to my mind.